# In Java, If a String contains zero and special characters, then it should return the below output using regex

Tags: java, java-8

##### Scenario 1:

```
Input String : 0000%  
Output : 0%
```

##### Scenario 2:

If the input string starts with %0000%, then the output should be 0%.

```
Input : %0000%
Output : 0%
```

##### Scenario 3:

- If the input starts with %0109, then it should return 109
- If input string is %109, it should return 109

##### Scenario 4:

```
Input String : 01234%  
Output : 1234% (leading zeros remove)
```

If first scenario is satisfied, return 0%, else return 2nd scenario output .

I have tried with regex for `^0+(?!$)`. The second scenario is satisfied, but 1st scenario fails.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly but if you want to remove/match all leading *continuous* zeroes except last one (before %) you could try with `^(0(?!%))+`?

Comment: Yes, it's working .but removing 1 zero only.it suppose to be 0% in case of 0000% or 000% or 00% or 0% also. And in case of 0 inputs string 0 should return. Thank you for quick response and help.

Comment: Maybe something like `return Long.parseLong(input.replaceAll("\\D", "")) + "%";`? or if you want a number then forget the string concatenation

Comment: "it suppose to be `0%` in case of 0000% or 000% or 00% or 0%" isn't that what already happens? Demo: https://ideone.com/ScEenX. "And in case of 0 inputs string 0 should return." that was never part of requirements mentioned in question. Please [edit] it to include examples which are not obvious (with expected resilts).

Comment: Added some other scenarios we have to satisfy by using regex. I have tried with using conditional statement, but no luck.          
                                                             Let me post here.                                    Scenario 2 :if input string is starts with %0000%, then out put should be 0% should return.
Input : %0000%
Output : 0% 
Scenario 3 : if input is starts with %0109, then it should return 109 
If input string is %109, it should return 109

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

- `^0+` - start of leading zeroes
- `(?=\\d)` - positive zero-width lookahead for a digit

If any number of `0's` match followed by any digit, remove them. So all leading digits up to, but excluding, the zero width lookahead will be removed.

```
for (String s : new String[] {"0000%", "01234%",
          "00001234%", "00023400%", "0023022%", "6662%"}) {
    String r = s.replaceFirst("^0+(?=\\d)", "");    
    System.out.printf("%10s -> %s%n", s, r);
}
```

prints

```
     0000% -> 0%
    01234% -> 1234%
 00001234% -> 1234%
 00023400% -> 23400%
  0023022% -> 23022%
     6662% -> 6662%
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... If first scenario satisfied, return 0%, else return 2nd scenario output . ..."*

You can use the following.

For `0000%`,

```
^0+%$
```

And, for `01234%`, check the prefix with *[String#startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))*, and use the *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method to remove the matched value.

```
^0+
```

```java
String value(String string) {
    if (string.matches("^0+%$")) return "0%";
    else if (string.startsWith("0")) return string.replaceAll("^0+", "");
    return string;
}
```

This will produce the following outputs, for `0000%` and `01234%`, respectively.

```
0%
1234%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a [percent format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getPercentInstance()) instead of complex regular expressions:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(System.in, System.console().charset()));

NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
format.setGroupingUsed(false);

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Input String : ");
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }

    Number number = format.parse(line);
    String s = format.format(number);
    System.out.println("Output : " + s);
}
```